# Proof of universal coefficient theorem in cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In the notes of a course of algebraic topoplogy, the universal coefficient theorem (for homology) is proven as it follows.

> Given the chain complex $\mathcal C$: $$\dots\to C_2\xrightarrow{\partial_2}C_1\xrightarrow{\partial_1}C_0\to 0,$$ call as usual $Z_n\subset C_n$ the subgroup of cycles and $B_n\subset C_n$ the subgroup of boundaries. Notice that one could define two more chain complexes (call them $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal Z$): $$\dots\to B_2\to B_1\to B_0\to 0;$$
> $$\dots\to Z_2\to Z_1\to Z_0\to 0,$$ where the boundary maps are all the zero map. Consider the exact sequences $$0\to Z_n \hookrightarrow C_n \xrightarrow{\partial_n} B_{n-1}\to 0,$$ and apply the functor $ -\otimes G$ to obtain again an exact sequence (since the $C_n$ are free by hypothesis). Moreover using as vertical maps the original boundary maps $\otimes G$, one obtains a exact sequence of chain complexes:$$0\to \mathcal Z \otimes G \to \mathcal C \otimes G\to \mathcal B' \otimes G ,$$ where $\mathcal B'$ is just $\mathcal B$ with the positions shifted by $1$. Then one constructs the corresponding long exact sequence, splits it and makes calculations to obtain the thesis.

My problem is that when proving the theorem in cohomology, the notes start with constructing a surjective homomorphism $q:H^n(\mathcal C, G)\to \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(\mathcal C), G)$, and then say that the prove of the existence of this exact splitting sequence: $$0\to \operatorname{Ext}(H_{n-1}(\mathcal C, G))\hookrightarrow H^n(\mathcal C, G)\xrightarrow{q} \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(\mathcal C), G) \to 0, $$ proceeds like the proof for homology. I don't understand how and where the two proofs link together; I mean, I don't understand why one can't follow the proof of the homology case dualizing all maps. Can anyone clarify my ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: Well you should follow the proof for homology and replace $-\otimes G$ by $\hom(-,G)$